# word that describes someone who gives everything away before they die?

Tags: single-word-requests

Requesting a word or something for a story please. it can be 1-3 words maximum, I have no ideas on what to describe it as.

Comment: What kind of "gives" are we talking about here?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. It is customary here to cite research one may have done before asking a question.. Your question will be much better accepted and answered if you do this.. Thanks

Comment: One word - 'sensible'.

Comment: self-divested--assuming it's more or less explained either before or afterward

Answer (score 1):

The best phrase I can think of would be "antemortem bestower".

The word "antemortem" means "before death", while "bestower" is defined as "a person who bestows". Ergo, the phrase "antemortem bestower" would mean "a person who gives things before they die".

This is fairly similar to "someone who gives everything away before they die", except it's lacking the "everything" part.

Answer (score 0):

Can you stretch to six words?

> **you can't take it with you.**
>   Enjoy material things while you're alive, as in Go ahead and buy the fancier car; you can't take it with you. This phrase gained currency as the title of a very popular play (1936) by George S. Kaufman and Moss Hart and of the 1938 film based on it. [First half of 1800s].
>   The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms by Christine Ammer.